# passing argument 1 of 'a function' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-call

Probably a really easy question, but I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe engine and this is the code (putting it later because despite me closing the triple graves it still puts it in code block if below for some reason)

I get warnings for:
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'resetboard' makes pointer from integer without a cast

[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'getnewboardO' makes pointer from integer without a cast

[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'printboard' makes pointer from integer without a cast

I'm a beginner, but I've worked with 2d bool arrays in nearly the same way in another project so I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
void getnewboardO(char board[3][3])
{
    char inputrow;
    
    int inputcoloumn;
    
    scanf("%c%d", &inputrow, &inputcoloumn);
    
    inputcoloumn--;
    
    if(inputrow=='A')
        board[0][inputcoloumn]='O';
    
    if(inputrow=='B')
        board[1][inputcoloumn]='O';
        
    if(inputrow=='C')
        board[2][inputcoloumn]='O';
}

void resetboard(char board[3][3])
{
    int i, j;
    
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
            board[i][j]='_';
    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        board[2][j]=' ';
}

void printboard(char board[3][3])
{
    printf("%c|%c|%c\n%c|%c|%c\n%c|%c|%c",board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2], board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2], board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
}


main()
{
    char board[3][3];
    
    resetboard(board[3][3]);
    
    printf("_|_|_\n_|_|_\n | |");
    
    getnewboardO(board[3][3]);
    
    printboard(board[3][3]);
}
```

Comment: `resetboard(board[3][3]);` ==> `resetboard(board);` The `board[3][3]` is an integer `char` value (but with out-of-range indexing), not the (pointer to the) array itself.

Comment: uh I must admit I kinda did what you said out of trust but it gave me a ton of     [Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Comment: @AnProg you didn't by any chance change `char board[3][3];` to `char board;` too or change the function signatures, did you?

Comment: There are two other occurrences to change too (calls to the other two functions). My test program compiles cleanly. Please note that I advised changing the call `resetboard(board[3][3]);` NOT `void resetboard(char board[3][3])`.

Comment: I'm an idiot sorry it compiles without warnings now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's for example consider this function declaration.

```
void getnewboardO(char board[3][3]);
```

The compiler will adjust the parameter having array type to pointer to the array element type.

That is this function declaration is equivalent to

```
void getnewboardO(char ( *board )[3]);
```

You could even declare the function like

```
void getnewboardO(char board[100][3]);
```

or

```
void getnewboardO(char board[10][3]);
```

in any case the both function declarations are adjusted by the compiler to the function

```
void getnewboardO(char ( *board )[3]);
```

However in the function call

```
getnewboardO(board[3][3]);
```

you are using a non-existent element of the array board of the type `char` because the valid range of the both indices is `[0, 3)`.

That is this expression used as an argument

```
board[3][3]
```

does not denote the declared array `board`. it denotes a scalar non-existent object of the type `char` that due to the integer promotions in turn is converted to the type `int`.

You need to pass the whole array to the function. That is what you need to write is

```
getnewboardO(board);
```

In this case the array designator will be converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[3]` as the type of the function parameter.